Remove trailing /feed from permalinks that use a .html suffix
I have permalinks with a .html suffix for backwards compatibility. I see in the Google Search console that my posts are getting /feed added, and as a result I get these URLs that 404:
https://example.com/2024/08/post-name.html/feed
How can I remove /feed from the end of the URL for single posts to clean up the 404's, but not remove the overall feed URL that is for the entire site, example.com/feed?

You can achieve this by adding the code to .htaccess file of your apache server.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([^/]+)\.html/feed/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3.html [R=301,L]

The given code will helps you in set up a redirect so that any request to a post URL with /feed appended will be redirected to the original post URL without the /feed suffix.
Using this way, the incorrect URLs won't result in 404 errors.

Thanks but I do not want to redirect. I want to remove the /feed from single post URLs. This should be possible in Wordpress and should not need htaccess in Apache.
